# How do I select specific columns when using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have code similar to the one below:

```
# pip install pymysql
# pip install sqlalchemy

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost:3306/db_name')

query = '''
select * from table_name
'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
print(df)
```

I would like to modify the select statement to just list specific columns and not all of them, as above. For example the csv file the code reads has a column name Player. To select the column Player, I tried

```
query = '''
select Player from table_name
'''
```

but it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: does it have a model?

Comment: can you also add the error ?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it, simple but it did not occur to me . I needed  backward slashes with quotes, not just quotes to surround Player.